# JIRA - tempo how to set total number of hours a resource can commit?

Tags: jira

Playing around with Tempo in JIRA at the moment, how can I set the total number of hours that a resource can commit, it seems by default it sets 8 hours per resource.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For general time tracking config you go to administration/issues/time tracking, there you can define amount of working hours per day and working days per week.

When you create a team in tempo, you can define the dedication or availability of each member on the team in x%

Comment: Yeah but it's always set to 8 hours.

Comment: you have to disable time tracking first, then you can change it. Believe me, I work 7,5 hours a day :)